# Do I need to install IE8 if I only use Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, internet-explorer

Do I need to install IE8 if I only use Firefox? I'm dual-booting Vista and XP. I never use IE in Vista. In XP I only use IE occasionally to check for Windows updates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you don't use IE for your browsing you won't benefit directly from installing it. However, many apps use the IE rendering engine to display html and they will benefit from the improved security in IE8.

My recommendation is to always install the latest updates for Windows wether you use that feature or not.

Answer (score 2):

Not for the time being, while IE7 is still getting security updates and Windows Updates still functions correctly under IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting the IE tab extension for firefox so you can get the functionality of IE without actually using the horid thing.

Comment: That's not really the point of this question. He doesn't want to use it, he said, he only wants to know about installing it or not, for security issues, for example.